# ZLIB decompression not working

Tags: java, android, json, zlib, compression

I have a raw string which is base64 compressed with zlib coming from the server and I need to convert it into JSON using zlib decompression. Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void decompress(String compressed) throws Exception {
    try {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
        inflater.setInput(compressed.getBytes());
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(compressed.getBytes().length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();

        String str = new String(output, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Logger.e("STR", str);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error while decompressing:

```
java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid code lengths set
```

at line `int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: A `String` is Unicode text and cannot contain arbitrary compressed bytes. Also mind that a `char` is 2 bytes, hence a waste of space. Receive the compressed data in a `ByteArrayInputStream` or such.

Comment: `compressed.getBytes()` - A String is *not* a byte array and cannot hold arbitrary binary data. Use some binary representation for network transfer or use String encoding/decoding (BASE64,...)

Comment: The parameter compressed is a base64 compressed with zlib string.

Comment: Then you have to decode the Base64 string into a byte array first.